# How to find and convert dates using html and jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

I am new here, I just want to ask how to find certain field and its value using html and jquery?

```
<form id="theForm">
    <input style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%;" name="startDate" tabindex="8" required="" data-role="datetimepicker" type="text" class="k-input">
    <select data-required-msg="Assigned To must be specified" required="required" id="assignedTo" name="assignedTo" data-role="multiselect" multiple="multiple" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;">
       <option value="441017201">Cat</option>
       <option value="441017201">Dog</option>
       <option value="441017201">Cow</option>
       <option value="441017201">Snake</option>
   </select>
</form>



<script>
    var form = $('[name="theForm"]');
    var date = form.find('[name="startDate"]').data('kendoTimePicker').value();
    var assignedTo = form.find('[id="assignedTo_taglist"]').data('kendoMultiSelect').value().join("|")
</script>
```

this is the error im getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `.val()` function in jQuery?  It's not clear how this is anything more than just a typo.

Comment: hello @David, Sorry for the confussion, what I want is to get the value on my `select option` and input type text

Comment: @LunaWest: The best place to start learning jQuery would be some introductory tutorials on jQuery.  `.value()` is indeed not a jQuery function.  Tutorials will show you how to use functions like `.val()`.

Answer (score 1):

var form needs to be like this, because you are fetching ID not Name attribute.

```
var form = $('#theForm');
```

Comment: Hi Nikola, how about the date?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?